# NullPointerException al agregar un "Vehiculo" en Java

Tags: java, herencia

Estoy practicando un poco de Java, para ello me propuse hacer un pequeño programa para agregar Vehiculos y herencia. Pero al hacer clic en el botón "Cargar" me tira un `NullPointerExcpetion`.

Mi código del botón *Cargar*:

```
String nombreTitular = txtNombreTitular.getText();
int dni              = Integer         .parseInt(txtDni.getText());
String patente       = txtPatente      .getText();
int modelo           = Integer         .parseInt(txtModelo.getText());
int tipoVehiculo     = cboTipo         .getSelectedIndex() + 1;

Vehiculo vehi = null;

switch (tipoVehiculo) {
    case 1:
        vehi = new Auto     (nombreTitular, dni, patente, modelo, tipoVehiculo);
        break;
    case 2:
        vehi = new Moto     (nombreTitular, dni, patente, modelo, tipoVehiculo);
        break;
    case 3:
        vehi = new Camioneta(nombreTitular, dni, patente, modelo, tipoVehiculo);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

concesionaria.agregarVehiculo(vehi);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Se ha cargado un nuevo vehiculo");
```

Cada `Vehiculo`, sea `Moto`, `Auto` o `Camioneta` tiene sus respectivos *set*, *get*, y un constructor con parámetros, por ejemplo este es el de `Moto`.

```
public Moto(String nombreTitular, int dni, String patente, int modelo, int tipoVehiculo) {
    super(nombreTitular, dni, patente, modelo, tipoVehiculo);
    this.tipoVehiculo = tipoVehiculo;
}
```

Y en mi clase `Concesionaria` tengo métodos, un `ArrayList` y mi método para agregar un nuevo `Vehiculo`

```
ArrayList<Vehiculo> vehiculos = new ArrayList<>();

public void agregarVehiculo(Vehiculo nuevo) {
    vehiculos.add(nuevo);
}
```

He probado de todo, pero el error persiste. Por alguna razón me esta tomando algún campo como vació. Si existe alguna forma de compartir el proyecto completo para una mejor ayuda, agradecería los medios para hacerlo sin complicaciones.

Comment: puede poner el stacktrace de la excepción que sale? para saber exactamente que variable está en null.

Comment: El error debe estar en el switch, debes estar haciendo algo mal con la variable 'tipodevehiculo' por lo que va al default y la variable vehi queda en null.

Comment: Moscoquera. Esto es lo que me sale:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at interfaz.FormCargar.btnCargarActionPerformed(FormCargar.java:144)
 at interfaz.FormCargar.access$000(FormCargar.java:19)
 at interfaz.FormCargar$1.actionPerformed(FormCargar.java:55)

Comment: No puedo comentar tu pregunta por falta de reputación, pero me gustaría ayudarte. ¿Qué editor de texto utilizas? Si utilizas algún IDE, prueba a *debugar* *. De esa forma sabrás si @MatiEzelQ lleva razón con su comentario. Si la variable `tipoVehiculo` tiene un valor no esperado (en teoría debería valer 1, 2 o 3) y por lo tanto `vehi` llega con valor `null` a esta línea `concesionaria.agregarVehiculo(vehi);` (por haber pasado al default del switch como dice el compañero @MatiEzelQ), ya sabes que el error está antes de todo ese código. Y te puedes centrar en cómo obtienes el valor de `tipoVehic

Comment: Por favor muestra el código de `Vehiculo`, de las clases hijas y del método que lanza el error.

Comment: Imprime el valor de tipo vehículo antes de entrar al switch para comprobar que sí tiene un valor válidom

Comment: Agrega `System.out.println()` dentro de los `cases` y el `default`, ejecuta el código y fíjate cual de todos imprime. Así sabrás mas específicamente donde se genera el error. Cuando el código a mi me falla, yo lo lleno de `System.out.println()` por todos los lados y de esa manera siempre doy con el error.

Answer (score 1):

No creo que el problema esté en que la variable vehi esté a `null`, como te han comentado se puede añadir un objeto `null` a un `ArrayList`.

Creo que el problema del `NullPointerException` está más en algún elemento del formulario y cuando haces la recogida de datos. ¿Qué línea del código es esta? `java.lang.NullPointerException at interfaz.FormCargar.btnCargarActionPerformed(FormCargar.java‌​:144)`

Answer (score 0):

te da ese error porque el vehículo los estas inicializando con null y en algun momento cuando evalues en el switch el tipoVehiculo cabe la posibilidad  que vaya a la opcion default eso indicaria que estarias agregando a tu colección de la clase padre un null.

Answer (score -1):

Te recomiendo que verifiques siempre tus objetos antes de hacer alguna operacion con ellos, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
ArrayList<Vehiculo> vehiculos = new ArrayList<>();

public void agregarVehiculo(Vehiculo nuevo) {
  if(nuevo != null){ //verifica si el objeto tiene valor
     vehiculos.add(nuevo);
  }
}
```

Estas son buenas practicas que tenes que acostumbrarte a usar sobretodo en el lenguaje java.

Comment: No, esto no es una buena práctica, es programación defensiva. Además, esto no va a generar un problema de NPE porque `ArrayList` no tiene ningún problema en agregar un elemento con valor `null`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Arraylist permite agregar valores null, pero a la hora de realizar operaciones con ese array saltaran los errores, Programación defensiva  = Buena practica.

Comment: No, no lo es, es una tendencia que surge como el "miedo" a evitar los NPEs. En su lugar, sería mejor utilizar `Optional` por sobre `null`. O, en última instancia, utilizar un valor por defecto que tenga elementos vacíos y no cause daños a la aplicación. Además que tener múltiples verificación de `null` en el código agrega complejidad ciclomática (muchas veces innecesaria, sobretodo al cubrirla con pruebas unitarias/de integración) y dificulta la lectura (claro, cuando hay 1 solo caso es imperceptible, pero si encuentras muchos de estos a lo largo del código se convierte en un *code smell*).